# rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph (Import error: no module named rospkg)(Is this is related to anaconda?)

Tags: ros, rosrun, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem started when i executed rosrun as mentioned in question, then i installed rospkg using command

> sudo apt-get install python-rospkg

and rospkg got installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg , but after that import error still showing. I am using anaconda too on my laptop and python2.7 is default for anaconda. One interesting point i got here that i have installed **rospkg** in python2.7 but when i am importing rospkg in **python3.4**, it is working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243261/rosrun-rqt_graph-rqt_graph-(import-error:-no-module-named--rospkg)(is-this-is-related-to-anaconda?)/) by [NEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23984/neo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-09-07**:
Please add `anaconda` to the title and tags since the problem is very likely related to that.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2016-09-08**:
What are the permissions on  /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospkg ?

**Comment by [NEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23984/neo/) on 2016-09-08**:
default for all user

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2016-09-09**:
I've had a case where I was not able to read some of the directories in dist-packages so when I did an import of that module, python was unable to do so. This is the reason why I was asking about the permissions.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2016-09-09**:
I also notice that on my machine, python2 and python2.7 somehow do different things.... So python -c "import rospkg" works, but python2.7 -c "import rospkg" does not... (just in case this isn't weird enough!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error occurs because only Python packages in /opt are added to PYTHONPATH environment. I'm reading about python-rospkg and I found that this package is installed in /usr. You only have to type "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"  and this line will be add in your .bashrc file.  In my case, that was the solution that fix the error.

---

Originally posted by [JuanmaOnse](https://answers.ros.org/users/28733/juanmaonse/) with karma: 16 on 2016-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adayoegi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33711/adayoegi/) on 2018-02-14**:
It works, thanks a lot!